# How do I allow only the most nested elements to be ACTIVE at one time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some nested elements which CSS controlling appearance when they are active.

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}

.test:active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="A">
  This is part A.
  <div class="test" id="B">
    This is nested part B.
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I mouse-down on the nested DIV (B), both A and B change color, instead of just B.

I tried capturing the mouse-down event and stopping propagation:

```
document.getElementById("B").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

When I do this, I see that the `mousedown` event handlers for "A" are not being called.  However, the "A" element has already changed its appearance to the active state by the time the captured event is fired!

How do I make enforce only allowing the actual most nested element being active at one time? I still need "A" to change background when it is active (mouse down on) but not when "B" is active.

Comment: It looks like B doesnt have a height so it may be the same size as A. it may be working like you expect.

Comment: Check out my solution, I think it may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector in this case:

```
.test > .test:active {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I need to update the question.  I still need "A" to change background when *it* is active.

Comment: But B is inside A, it will change too (?)

Comment: Yes, I need A to change background when it is active but B is not, and B (only) to change background when it is active.  Is that not possible?

Comment: I got the clever idea to give them separate classes (test1 and test2 for A and B) and then add this one to yours: ".test1:active > .test2 {
  background: blue;
}
" but alas, that applies to the child node, not the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JavaScript, which will check to see if a given element has any children with the `.test` class. In the future this can be done with the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS selector, but does not have stylesheet support in any browser yet.

The below demo will only turn blue if it is the "most-nested" `.test` element in a given structure, which I believe that is what you were looking for.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!event.target.querySelector(".test")) {
      event.target.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
  elem.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(function (elem) {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="A">
  This is part A.
  <div class="test" id="B">
    This is nested part B.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test" id="C">
  This is part C.
</div>

<div class="test" id="D">
  This is part D.
  <div class="test" id="E">
    This is nested part E.
    <div class="test" id="F">
      This is nested-nested part F.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**----EDIT----**

After clarification, it seems like you really don't care about the "most-nested" element being the only thing becoming active, what you really want is just only the single element that was moused-down on to become active. If that is the case, it is actually simpler. The code would look like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.classList.add("active");
  });
  elem.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: not quite, I still need the ancestor elements to change background if they are clicked on by themselves.  but, with a javascript only solution i think that would be just an addition to your solution...

Comment: @Michael So.. this really has nothing to do with having only the "most nested elements be active", you just want to change the background of a single div when it is clicked on mousedown?